# nodejs clientCertificateAuth always returns false

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

i`am using the following node module to authenticate client request on my routes: https://github.com/tgies/client-certificate-auth

```
var checkAccess = function(cert) {
    return User.findOne({ 'subject': cert.subject.ST }, function (err, user) {
        if (!err) {
            if (user.active === true) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
};

app.post('/test', clientCertificateAuth(checkAccess), function(req, res) {
    //...
});
```

The problem is, checkAccess always return: false
I think it`s because the mongoose query is async.

Is there a way to wait for the database result?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to this;

```
var checkAccess = function(req, res, next) {
        User.findOne({ 'subject': cert.subject.ST }, function (err, user) {
            if (!err) {
                if (user.active === true) {
                    console.log("User active found");
                    req.result = true;
                    next();
                }
                else {
                    console.log("User active not found");
                    req.result = false;
                    next();
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error occured while fetching user");
                req.result = false;
                next();
            }
        });
    };
```

And in your controller;

```
app.post('/test', checkAccess, function(req, res, next) {
    if (clientCertificateAuth(req.result) != true) {
        console.log("Invalid cert due to active user not found");
        next("Invalid certificate");
    }
});
```

What I did above is; simply call a function in controller request and I updated `req.result` according db result. And I have used that result in controller for `clientCertificateAuth`

Your `return` statement response nothing, because mongoose query may not been completed

Comment: thank you for the fast reply, but it`s the same problem. There is always: false

Comment: now, it`s always true. if i minimize the if/else and only return false, it`s anyway: true

Comment: Have you got any user has status true?

Comment: @Pumper I have added console.log to my code . Could you please test and see what it prints on console

Comment: the log says: User active found

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48344/discussion-between-pumper-and-huseyin-babal)

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL This isn't going to work for a few reasons:
`clientCertificateAuth(req.result)` -- why are you passing a boolean here? It takes a function. `clientCertificateAuth(function () { return req.result })` would do what you're trying to do, I guess.
In the `checkAccess` function you are looking at `cert` but `cert` doesn't necessarily exist because you're no longer getting it passed to you by `clientCertificateAuth`.
I am the developer of the module -- you can find the documentation here: https://github.com/tgies/client-certificate-auth

Answer (score 1):

Author of the client-certificate-auth module here.

Your main issue is `return User.findOne(...)` -- your function is returning right here instead of waiting for the async call.

The 0.3 release that came out in March handles asynchrony in the authorization check a lot better. Just provide a function that takes two parameters, i.e. `checkAccess(cert, done)`. `clientCertificateAuth` will pass you a callback function, then you call `done(true)` for success or `done(false)` for failure:

```
var checkAccess = function(cert, done) {
    User.findOne({ 'subject': cert.subject.ST }, function (err, user) {
        if (!err && user.active) {
            done(true);
        }
        else {
            done(false);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: thank you for the information, i still use your component and it works very nice